# How to speed up updating IP address in DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy, domain, ip

I have a website on VPS. I pretty often move it to another hosting and thus its IP address changes. I have a reason to do so. It has nothing to do with blacklisting or the like.

My question: how can I get it to become accessible as quickly as possible after I've moved it? I mean, the DNS-related stuff, namely how can I speed up updating its IP address or whatever needed?

Note that I don't want to use any paid third-party service. Building some kind of proxy by myself will be acceptable, though.

Answer (score 2):

If changing the IP address is your only option, then DNS updates are always going to take some time to reflect those changes.

However, if your DNS is hosted with a provider that will replicate your changes immediately, then you can set the TTL (time to live) for the DNS record to its lowest possible value.

TTL tells all the DNS servers around the world how long to cache your IP address before making a new request for the updated IP.

Usually minimum time is around 5 minutes.

This answers your question, however, the obvious and proper solution involves the elimination of changing IPs.

Comment: 1) only 5 minutes? in 5 minutes it'll be accessible? I've been told that it'll take about a day.

Comment: 2) how long will it take to update TTL? say, TTL was 1 day, then I change it to 5 minutes, then I move my website to a new IP. And next I want to increase TTL back to 1 day.

Comment: I don't understand your strange request to begin with, but now you are suggesting you want to continually change your TTL back and forth? This is even stranger. If you have a good DNS hosting provider set, and LEAVE, the TTL to its smallest possible value. After the old TTL expires all future updates will occur within that new TTL period you set. There is no reason to keep changing it. If your host won't honor your DNS updates and IMMEDIATELY apply them, get a new host. There are plenty that work properly.

Comment: then why do high TTL values exist at all?

Comment: Stable sites: my colo'ed box hasn't changed its IP in six years, why would I load my DNS servers more than they need to be loaded?  That said, your plan of lowering the TTL before a cutover then raising it again after, is a good and common one, despite Appleoddity's comments.  Just  remember to lower the TTL *more than one day before the cutover*, otherwise people may well have the old value and its TTL cached some hours past the cutover.

Comment: @MadHatter, thx.

Comment: Minimum TTL on standards compliant implementations is 0 seconds.

Comment: If the IP address is stable then a higher TTL makes sense. If it changes often then a low TTL makes sense. The higher TTL can slightly improve response times on heavily used sites. We're talking milliseconds. It can also keep a site live for a little longer in the event of a DNS outage. But, loading is a non-issue.